# Python: get an element from a tuple in an iterated list

Tags: python, list, tuples

I have a list of tuples I'm iterating through, and using a formatter to get part of those tuples at different points. The formatter keeps giving me errors.

Every tuple in the list is formatted like ("name, "HH:MM:SS")

```
trackNum = 0
for i in markers:
    trackNum = trackNum + 1
    track = '''
    TRACK %s AUDIO
    \t TITLE "%s"
    \t INDEX 01 %s
    '''  % (str(trackNum).zfill(2), markers[i][0], markers[i][1])
```

If I just use the plain [i] in the formatter, I get the error "List indices must be integers, not tuple". If I use [int(i)], I get "int() argument must be a string or a number, not 'tuple'"

Comment: If you want to iterate the list by `for i in markers` ,  maybe you can use `i[0]` not `markers[i][0]`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If `markers` is the list of tuples, then in this code -

```
for i in markers:
```

`i` represent a single tuple.

So you should use `i[0]` instead of `markers[i][0]`. Same for 
`markers[i][1]`

As `i` is a tuple and you are using `markers[i]...`, python gave that error as tuple is used for indexing the list

Answer (score 2):

Replace the `marker[i]` with just `i` since you're iterating using the `tuple` not `range(tuple)`.

```
trackNum = 0
for i in markers:
    trackNum = trackNum + 1
    track = '''
    TRACK %s AUDIO
    \t TITLE "%s"
    \t INDEX 01 %s
    '''  % (str(trackNum).zfill(2), i[0], i[1])
```

Being that case, naming that variable `i` isn't the best idea, since `i` usually refers to index. Maybe change it to `for marker in markers:`?

Other than that, your code can be condensed further using `enumerate`:

```
for trackNum, marker in enumerate(markers, start = 1):        
    track = '''
    TRACK %s AUDIO
    \t TITLE "%s"
    \t INDEX 01 %s
    '''  % (str(trackNum).zfill(2), marker[0], marker[1])
```

Comment: @pawood, I agree with abccd. You should name the variable a little more meaningfully. it will help you avoid problem later on. Also try to use `enumerate` as he suggested. @abccd, upvoted for those suggestions

Answer (score 0):

@abccd provides you the concise way to solve your problem.
The only thing I would add is I would do this with `str.format()` instead of the old style substitutions:

```
for trackNum, marker in enumerate(markers, 1):
    track = '''
    TRACK {:02} AUDIO
    \t TITLE "{}"
    \t INDEX 01 {}
    '''.format(trackNum, *marker)
```